# Is there a bash script to update the hosts file by retrieving a list from a website?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'd like to use a bash script to automatically update my hosts file on Windows 10 using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Debian), by retrieving an online list (e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts).

I'm aware there are Windows Powershell scripts such as:
https://github.com/robledosm/update-mvpsHosts/blob/master/update-mvpsHosts.ps1
https://github.com/chriskenis/POSH/blob/master/OS/Update-HostFile.ps1

But I'm after a Linux script as I already have basic Linux knowledge.

Can someone please point me to such a script?

Thanks

EDIT: BANJOSA's answer is indeed correct. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to update your hosts file? It's not commonly used now a days.

Comment: Hi. There are certain domains that I don't want my machine to connect to. Mostly annoyances / possible malware.

Comment: Whew, for a second there I thought we were reinventing pre-DNS Internet!

Comment: did my answer solved the issue?

Comment: Since BANJOSA’s answer worked for you, please accept it (by clicking the big check mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Subsystem for Linux is somewhat limited when edit system files from the host. To achieve this you need to run the **WSL** with **Administrator** privileges.

A very rough example of a script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc || { echo "Aborting all operations! Path does not exist."; exit 1; }
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts -o hosts_from_internet
sed -i 1,13d hosts_from_internet
cat hosts_from_internet >> hosts
awk '!seen[$0]++' hosts
```

**CD** - Enter the directory, if it doesn't succeed, it will abort with the message and stops the execution of the script.

**curl** - will download the list from the link you've provided and save it in a file.

**sed** - will remove the first 13 lines from the downloaded file. Since those lines are just comments, I assumed you will not want them in your hosts file.

**cat** - will append the file you've downloaded to your hosts file.

**awk** - will check the hosts file for duplicates and remove them. This might be useful when you run the script more than once.